# MySql Trigger for notification

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, lambda, database-trigger

In a table in MySql database, I have a boolean column with 'Yes' and 'No' for appointment confirmation. As soon as appointment gets 'Yes', a notification is sent via an AWS Lambda call. 
I want to send a 12 hour prior notification before the day of the appointment. What is the best way to do that in My Sql utilizing triggers or stored procedure or any other way?

Comment: The canonical method is probably to schedule a job every hour and run a set of notifications all at once.  You can also use events, to specifically set up an event exactly 12 hours before.  That said, I don't know that 12 hours is a good timeframe.  If an appointment is at 3:00 p.m., do you really want to send someone a notification at 3:00 a.m.?

Comment: correct, sending a notification at 3:00am would be of no use. 
I guess best would be to schedule a Job every 12 hours before, or in the prior morning of the working next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How precise do you need the notifications to be?

If you simple want for example to have the notification at 13:00 before the day, you can use a simple cron to run every day at 12:50 (depending on your setup).

If you want the notification to be 12 hours before the day depending on the booked time, for example booking is made 20:00 10.10.2020, notification is sent at 08:00 09.10.2020, you can set your cron to run every 5 minutes (again depending on your workload) and have it send notifications for that time period.

If you want precise notifications I would recommend using an external tool for the job, for example RabbitMQ with Delayed Messages plugin.

If the above is not an option you can use an "always on" script that checks for changes each second.

Comment: Right. MySQL cannot generate outbound messages itself. You must write code to poll the database and generate those messages.  Careful: polling databases too often can get quite expensive. It would be great to have `WHENEVER table.timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR SEND table.user whatever;` But SQL doesn't have that. :-(